# Phone not booting after rooting attempt

Tags: rooting, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-j1

I tried to root my phone Samsung Galaxy J1 (SM-J100H) with Odin3 software following some steps, but after that now it's not working, I turned on the phone and it vibrates one time and I see only the Samsung logo and nothing else. I tried too wipe all data and factory reset but it doesn't do anything. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory reset won't undo rooting since it only clears the `/data` partition and not `/system`.

What you should do to get your device working is flash a stock ROM with Odin.  You can get one from [sammobile.com](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-J100H/).  As usual, you would put the `.tar` file from there into the AP/PDA field of Odin and flash it while the phone is connected in Download mode.

Comment: I get this error: Complete(Write) operation failed.  http://i.imgur.com/6QBQg04.jpg Please so much help me to solve this.  can you suggest me a version please? 1.85 is good?

Comment: @Dimas The versions are in the PDA column, things like `J100HXXU0APB3` not `1.85`.  Just filter by your country/carrier and then try the second-newest, or maybe the oldest, etc.  I don't have this phone so I don't know what versions are the best. Maybe try Romania?

Comment: @Dimas No problem, glad it's working!