# Odin BcmCP.img fail when trying to flash gt-s5830i (galaxy ace)

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-ace, odin

So I have a bricked gt-s5830i (galaxy ace) and when I try to flash it using odin I get this error:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Binary Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1100)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> sbl.bin
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> BcmCP.img
<ID:0/003> FAIL!
<ID:0/003> 
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/003> Removed!!
```

It started boot looping after it randomly got stuck and I took out the battery since I couldn't do anything at all. This is the firmware I tried: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/37194/S5830IXXLK3_S5830IDBTLK1_DBT/
http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/14913/S5830ZXXLK3_S5830ZDBTLK2_DBT/

Does anyone know what's causing this? This is also the first time I'm flashing a phone. The rom was downloaded from sammobile because the ones from samsung-updates seem to have broken downloads.

Comment: While waiting for answers on your question, please check [these other questions with similar problems](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Complete%28Write%29+operation+failed.). Might find your solution there already.

Comment: Maybe try [this one](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/14913/S5830ZXXLK3_S5830ZDBTLK2_DBT/) instead, or try another country -- some of them seem to fail randomly.  Someone had a similar issue [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/139661/1465) with a different device.  I'd also suggest doing a battery pull, connecting the device, and then holding Volume Down while you reinsert the battery to get into Download Mode -- my old Vibrant always flashed more reliably when I did it that way.

Comment: No luck, I got the exact same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Use Odin 3.07. Also, make sure that you start odin as administrator. I had the same problem, and it worked for me. And prior to that, if it gets stuck in Setup Connection, just boot into "download mode" once again by pulling off the battery and re-inserting it.